# Storing & reading custom metadata in parquet files using Spark / Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

I know parquet files store meta data, but is it possible to add **custom** metadata to a parquet file, using Scala (preferably) using Spark?

The idea is that I store many similar structured parquet files in a Hadoop storage, but each has a  uniquely named source (String field, also present as column in the parquet file), however, I'd like to access this information without creating the overhead of actually reading the parquet and possibly even removing this redundant column from the parquet.

I really don't want to put this info in a filename, so my best option is now just to read the first line of each parquet and use the source column as String field.

It works, but I was just wondering if there is a better way.

Comment: Is the metadata you're looking for http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType@add(name:String,dataType:org.apache.spark.sql.types.DataType,nullable:Boolean,metadata:org.apache.spark.sql.types.Metadata):org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType? See the last parameter. Never used this before.

Comment: Not sure, but I don't think so. It seems to have more to do with the structure of the field/column instead of it's contents. I'll look into it though. 
Thanks anyway for the quick reply

Comment: @TomLous Hi, I have the similar use case to implement. How did you manage to do it?

Comment: I added a field that named the source and forced writers to add that field to each record of each parquet file. Pretty: no. Effective: yes

Comment: This may help: https://ndolgov.blogspot.com/2016/10/parquet-file-metadata-standard-and.html